# csv parser returns first column which is a date as undefined, but returns the second date column perfectly fine

Tags: javascript, mongodb, csv, mongoose

Basically title. I have a csv file which contains journey logs. When parsing the file to save it to the database the first column Departure gets saved as undefined, but the second column Return which is the exact same format gets returned properly.

Here is the code im running

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const fs = require('fs')
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
})

const uri = "mongodb+srv://<account>:<password>@cluster0.fjhmv.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
mongoose.connect(uri)
.then(() => {
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB Atlas');
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log('Failed to connect to MongoDB Atlas:', error)
})

const journeySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Departure: String,
  Return: String,
  'Departure station id': Number,
  'Departure station name': String,
  'Return station id': Number,
  'Return station name': String,
  'Covered distance (m)': Number,
  'Duration (sec.)': Number
}, { strict: false }
);

const Journey = mongoose.model('Journey', journeySchema);


fs.createReadStream('logs.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', async (data) => {
    // Parse and validate the data
    const journey = {
      Departure: String (data.Departure),
      Return: String (data.Return),
      'Departure station id': Number(data['Departure station id']),
      'Departure station name': data['Departure station name'],
      'Return station id': Number(data['Return station id']),
      'Return station name': data['Return station name'],
      'Covered distance (m)': Number(data['Covered distance (m)']),
      'Duration (sec.)': Number(data['Duration (sec.)'])
    };

    if (journey['Covered distance (m)'] >= 10 && journey['Duration (sec.)'] >= 10) {
      try {
        // Create a new journey and save it to the database
        const newJourney = new Journey(journey);
        await newJourney.save();
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Failed to save error', error);
      }
    }
  })
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log('All data has been imported');
    mongoose.disconnect();
  })
  .on('error', (error) => {
    console.log('Failed to parse document', error);
  });
```

I tried changing the property on the Schema to Date format but then it gives me the current Date and not the date from the file. Its all good I can have it as a string I just need to actually get it returned and not undefined.

Here is how a line from the csv file looks if its any help.

```
Departure,Return,Departure station id,Departure station name,Return station id,Return station name,Covered distance (m),Duration (sec.)
2021-05-31T23:57:25,2021-06-01T00:05:46,094,Springfield,100,Wintersgate,2043,500
```

Thanks in advance and apologies if anything is confusing.